# The software for finite field arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any software, library,or toolkit that support arithmetic with normal basis on $GF(2n)$ field? What is the best one?

Especially, which software can implement the conversion between normal bases and polynomial bases of finite fields?

Comment: mathematica seems to be able.

Comment: The package in mathematica only supports limited functions. Is there some more powerful tools or packages?

Comment: there is a seperates se for mathematica you can check, other then that I don't know

Comment: Have you looked into [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org)?

Comment: I have used sage for symbolic algebra. Thanks for letting me know it can be used for finite fields

Comment: See also GAP (http://www.gap-system.org). This is the manual chapter: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap59.html

Comment: In python there is the `galois` package that supports arithmetic in arbitrary GF(q), q=p^n. But I frown on your "2n" which cannot be a field unless n = 2^k.